# what should we do if we don't have a view for a particular controller?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a controller say `class_controller.php`. But I don't want to create its view. So what should be written in the controller?

I like if you don't want any model to be related we use `var $uses = null;` likewise what is the code for not relating to its view?

Comment: I didnt get your question, controller can execute without view, if you don't want to use simply dont load it

Comment: It's the `methods` in your controller that requires a `view` which is by default will look for it's own view. You can override the auto rendering of view by usin `$this->autoRender = FALSE;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to disable both the layout and view in CakePHP by putting the following line in your controller action:

`$this->autoRender = false;`

If you want to disable just the layout, use the following line in your controller action:

`$this->layout = false;`

And if you only want to disable the view for this action, use the following line in your controller:

`$this->render(false);`

*Note*: This will be action specific and not controller as you have asked for.

You can do the trick using `beforeFilter()` function which will call before every action in your controller & disable layout for you.

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->autoRender = false;
}
```